# How to deploy to Django digital ocean droplet made using the using the one-click installer

Tags: python, django

I plan to host a Django application on a Digital Ocean droplet created using the Django one click installer. This seems to be Ubuntu  14.04, Django 1.6.1, Python 2.7.6, Gunicorn and Nginx.

I plan to develop the application on my Windows 7 machine and I want to be able to deploy it easily to the Digital Ocean droplet. In order to be able to deploy the application easily, what environment should I set up on my Windows 7 machine? I'd prefer to use free software.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way -  **git**. You can update your django project with him...
[Git Docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Public Git services: 
www.github.com
www.bitbucket.com

*Sorry, cant add more 2 links ;)*

Tutorial for deploy django project on DO:
[DO Turorial for django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps)
gl...